# How can get time difference between current time and eventTime

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am working in php. i have a table EVENT. in which there are three fields, **EventID,EventName and EventTime.**

i have used **datetime** format for **EventTime** field.

now i want to write a query which return difference between current time and time of events.

I want my result to print like this:- **eventID occurred 1 hour 20 minutes ago**.

please suggest me how can i do this.

Thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT EventID, TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), EventTime), 'occured %H hour %i minutes ago') diff FROM table;
```

---

```
SELECT EventID, CONCAT('occured ', hours, IF(hours > 1, ' hours ', ' hour '), minutes, IF(minutes > 1, ' minutes', ' minute'), ' ago') FROM (
  SELECT EventID, 
    @diff:=TIMEDIFF(NOW(), EventTime),
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM @diff) hours,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM @diff) minutes
  FROM EVENT) t;
```

Comment: This is probably the best way if you want to do it in pure MySQL, the only drawback as far as I can see is it'll return for instance "00 hour and 19 minutes ago" or "07 hour and 01 minutes ago".

Comment: thank you sir... please tell me what should i do if i want to show only "19 minutes ago" if hour is less than 1 ? if hour is 1 or more than 1 then this should show hour and minutes also...

Comment: @zrvan You are right. In this case we should check these values and format values manually.

Comment: @Pushpendra Kuntal I have added one more query.

Comment: @Devart: I was impressed by the extra effort from your side, so I took your solution and ran with it, the `CONCAT` part could be changed to: `CONCAT('occured',
    CASE WHEN hours = 0
      THEN ''
    WHEN hours = 1
      THEN CONCAT(' ', hours, ' hour')
    ELSE
       CONCAT(' ', hours, ' hours')
    END,
    CASE WHEN minutes = 0
      THEN ''
    WHEN minutes = 1
      THEN CONCAT(' ', minutes, ' minute')
    ELSE
      CONCAT(' ', minutes, ' minutes')
    END,
   ' ago')`

Answer (score 0):

I done this completely like this:-

```
SELECT
  placeID,
  IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), comment_datetime) > '01:00:00',
    TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), comment_datetime), 'occured %H hour %i minutes ago'),
    TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), comment_datetime), '%i minutes ago')
  ) diff
FROM
  place_comments;
```